# How to enforce role selection on the user's create, so they can edit other certain users?

Tags: users

I have three roles.

- registry
- teachers
- students

  How do I enforce role selection on user's creation?

  2. I want the registry role to create and edit users (**ONLY** teachers or students role).

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! You should show what you tried, in particular which modules you found on drupal.org that could suit your use case.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Auto Assign Role](https://www.drupal.org/project/autoassignrole) module. 
This [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/216868) will help you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Look at [Profile2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2_regpath) & [Profile2 Registration Path](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2_regpath) for having multiple role signup forms.
2. For limited role assignment checkout [RoleAssign](https://www.drupal.org/project/roleassign).